# Starting activities problem? Theme problem

Tags: android, android-activity, themes

I got some very strange problem:

Let's say I've got two activities.

If I launch each one of them as the main activity of the application - everything seems great.

But if I launch, let's say activity A from activity B. Activity A has the same theme settings as activity B.

Why is this happening?

Activity A is translucent, and if I start the application from activity A - it is transparent, but if I start it from activity B - it is not??

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gg.thesis.gallant.command" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".viewall.A" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
            <intent-filter>
<!--    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->
<!--    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".viewall.B" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

....

Is there any theme inheritance for the activities in Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

write one line in your second activity tag....

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"


<activity android:name=".viewall.B" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
</activity>
```

may be work...